# CSS maximum height same as dynamic width (non-fixed aspect ratio)

Tags: html, css

I have a site that uses percentage widths to create columns of images.  We have a desire to have the images have a maximum height equal to their maximum width.  That is to say, if the image container has a width of 33.33%, and that comes to 125px, we want the maximum height of the image to be the same, so that the long edge of all images will always be the same length, regardless of their aspect ratio or orientation.

I have seen various examples of maintaining a block's aspect ratio through use of padding and an absolutely positioned element within:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper:after {
  padding-top: 100%;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}
.main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

However, this creates a box with a fixed ratio that does not behave in the "min/max" manner.

An example of the kind of list we have, with different aspect-ratio images can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/sxk4bh6f/1/

Ideally, we would like to *not* use Javascript.

**Clarification:**
If the list-containing element is 1000px, and List Item's have a width of `33.33%`, they will be `333.3px` wide.  Inside the list item is an Image container, disregarding padding/margins (let's not talk about that at this time) they will have a width of `100%` or `333.3px`.  The image within has CSS that makes it maintain aspect ratio, with a `max-width:100%`, making the maximum width of the image `333.3px`.  This is easy.  However, a Portrait image, while having a maximum-width of `333.3px`, may grow to a height of more than that.

Our goal is to have the maximum height of the image the same as the maximum width of the image, without explicitly setting it (allow for the list container to size above and below `1000px`, which in turn makes the List Item's width change, which in turn would make the maximum-height of the images within change).

*One last clarification*:

You have two images in the list.  The List Container is `500px` wide, and List Items are set to `50%` width.  This means that List Items are only allotted `250px` width.  If both images are `2:1` aspect ration, but one is portrait and one is landscape, the portrait image should maintain aspect ratio without clipping, and not exceed the allotted width: `250px`.  Such that the height of any individual image will never exceed the allotted width of it's container.

If the List Container then expands to `1000px`, each list item will then be allotted `500px`.  As such, the landscape image will expand to `500px` wide, and the portrait image will expand to `500px` tall.

We are aiming to accomplish this in CSS only, no Javascript.

**Updated Link**: I had the wrong example link before.  I have updated it above.  The link below is a link to an example of maintaining aspect ration for divs that we were trying to use to make this happen.  But it was not working.

http://jsfiddle.net/sxk4bh6f/

**Progress**:

By adding a wrapper around the image (eh, I am not sure I like modifying the html) I was able to accomplish *most* of what is desired.

http://jsfiddle.net/4crswgxx/3/

However, if the image does not have the width/height resolution, it will not fill to the top/bottom edge (ie: if one image is landscape 100px wide, and another is landscape 200px wide, and the List Item width is 150px, the 200px will extend to the sides, but the 200px will not).  This can be mitigated by setting `width: 100%`, but then if we flip this and say we are talking about height, we then have to do the same for height, at which point, we get the image all distorted and in a square.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question - do you mean that you want your images to crop to a square, based on the width, or that you want the height to be proportional to the dynamic width?

Comment: If you want to have exact height as fluid width - in your example 333.33px - you will have to do it with simple JS code. I dont know any other way.

Comment: Not exact height, maximum-height.

Comment: The same solution. I can write sample JS (jquey) for you, its simple.

Comment: I understand the JS is simple, but the platform we are using deals with custom client CSS, and modifying or inserting JS for individual clients is something we are trying to avoid.

Comment: @Mike: A question.  In case of a smaller outer width of list element with a portrait like image with eg. 200 x 500 px size. Should the image be cropped off or shrink/stretch...